# Use of variables in a function for ggplot2 in R (use in scale_x_discrete)

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have created a function to create a plot in ggplot2, one of the requirementes is to sort the bar chart according to the score results for each bar. For this, I have rearranged the data frame but when I try to use the scale_x_discrete with the function variable (Geog), it just doesnt work:

```
f_OS_RegionF <- function(Geog) {

  #Carrier Mean Score###########
  mean_c<-mean(co_dataa$Score)
  ###########################

  #Region=deparse(substitute(Region))
  data_carr<-co_dataa
  ScorexGeog_C <- cast(data_carr, as.formula(paste(Geog,"Carrier",sep="~")), mean, value="Score")

  names(ScorexGeog_C)[2] <- "Score"
  ScorexGeog_C[2]<-round(ScorexGeog_C[2],digits=1)

  ScorexGeog_C<- ScorexGeog_C[order(ScorexGeog_C$Score), ] 
  write.table(ScorexGeog_C,file="ScorexGeog_C_F_Check.csv",sep=",",row.names=F, col.names=T)

  d <-  ggplot(ScorexGeog_C, aes_string(x=Geog, y="Score", fill=Geog))+ 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="white")+

        coord_flip()+
        scale_fill_manual(values = coloress)+

        scale_x_discrete(limits=paste("ScorexGeog_C",Geog,sep="$"))+

        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank())+   
        theme(legend.position = "none") +

        geom_text(data=ScorexGeog_C,aes_string(x=Geog,y="Score",label="Score"),colour="white",vjust=0.5,hjust=2,size=2.5, fontface="bold")+
        geom_text(data=ScorexGeog_C,aes_string(x=Geog,y=0.3,label=Geog),colour="white", angle=0, vjust=0.5, hjust=0, fontface="bold",size=2)+      

        geom_hline(yintercept=mean_c, colour = "gray",linetype="solid", size =1, alpha=.8)

  print(d)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example data and a description of the error you are receiving? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Limits are numbers, why do you use paste function there?

Comment: Limits are discrete variables. I used the paste function as the Geog variable is defined in the function f_OS_RegionF <- function(Geog).

Comment: Limits are discrete variables. I used the paste function as the Geog variable is defined in the function f_OS_RegionF <- function(Geog). I tried to use directly scale_x_discrete(limits=ScorexGeog_C$Geog) and despite and I dont get any error the plot does not rearranges.

Comment: The error I get is "data must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' Calls..."

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you are trying to do, but possibly try `ScorexGeog_C[[Geog]]` in `scale_x_discrete` instead of the `paste` code you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! perfectly!